# How to printout answer from Google using selenium, BeautifulSoup and headless Google

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to make a program which fetches answer from Google using selenium and headless Google for every question.

This program works fine unless I don't change the `text` string. Because Google classes keep changing with every `text` string.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
text='How to make pie'
text.replace(" ","+")
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q='+text)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
copiedText = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.Y0NH2b.CLPzrc"))).text
print(copiedText)
driver.quit()
```

So I found on Internet the alternative which according to them should work fine for every `text` string. They said that soup library method soup.find_all() find the class for every Google search. I copied the same coding but it gives me error "index out of range".

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import sys


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
text="Who is the author of Harry Potter"
text.replace(" ","+")
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q='+text)
#driver.implicitly_wait(5)
time.sleep(10)
copiedText = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "gsfi"))).text
print(copiedText)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
answer=soup.find_all(class_="_sPg")[0]
#print(answer)
print(answer.get_text())
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Exactly which text are you looking for? Can you give the example text for either `'How to make pie'` or `"Who is the author of Harry Potter"`

Comment: @debanjanB I want to make a general program so that no matter what i search, it fetches me the answer. I found that for every different google search, we have to face a new class. What do we do then?

Answer (score 2):

Code:

`answer = soup.find(class_="Z0LcW")`

If I search for `class` with value of `Z0LcW`, then I get the answer of the google search which is `J. K. Rowling`.

I tried the same questions on multiple browsers and this tag that you are looking for is always the same for now as seen below.

`<div class="Z0LcW">J. K. Rowling</div>`

I cannot guarantee you that the class name `Z0LcW` will be the same all the time to your answer as I believe it auto-generated.

Different question text `How old is Messi?` example:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import sys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
text="How old is messi?"
text.replace(" ", "+")
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + text)
time.sleep(10)
copiedText = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "gsfi"))).text
print(copiedText)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
answer = soup.find(class_="Z0LcW")
print(answer.get_text())
driver.quit()
```

Output:

`30 years`

Comment: `soup.find(class_="Z0LcW")`

Comment: Yes the find_all() function seems redundant in this situation. I updated my answer. :)

Comment: @keyur potdar and Ali I am looking for neither the answer to the author of harry potter nor to how to make pie. I want to make a such program, which fetches me answer, no matter what i google. It seems like google changes its class for almost every answer. What do we do then?

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible to do because that would require google to somehow answer all your questions even if it is gibberish. There are scenarios where you ask questions and all what you get is web results (meaning websites to visit) not a specific answer like.
To understand what I mean try googling `how old am I?`, you will get not answer. But if you google a mainstream question like `Who is the author of Harry Potter?`, Google will provide you an answer, which makes it possible for your code to parse the answer Google spits out.

Comment: Yes @user9181286 guessed it right. Please Ali read his comment below

Comment: @NaufilMuhammad I edited my answer to prove that your script can work with different questions texts as long as the `class` is always `Z0LcW`

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no need in `selenium` since the data you want is in the HTML and you can do it with [`beautifulsoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/):

[image]

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/how-to-printout-answer-from-google-using-selenium-beautifuls#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "How old is messi?",  # search query
    "hl": "en",                # language
    "gl": "us"                 # country to search from 
    }

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.87 Safari/537.36",
    }

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

answer = soup.select_one(".Z0LcW").text
print(answer)

# 34 years
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The main difference is that you don't have to figure out the extraction part, which selectors to use, how to maintain the parser over time if something in the HTML will be changed, how to scale it, and how to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines.

Example code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # Your SerpApi API key
    "engine": "google",               # search engine
    "q": "How old is messi?",         # search query
    "gl": "us",                       # country to search from
    "hl": "en"                        # language
    }

search = GoogleSearch(params)         # where data extraction happens
results = search.get_dict()           # JSON -> Python dictionary

answer = results["answer_box"]["answer"]
print(answer)

# 34 years
```

> Disclaimer, I work at SerpApi.